# AWS lambda Converting inbound PDF to JPGS

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, aws-lambda

Currently i am doing a simple copy with a lambda function in node.js where i copy an incoming pdf file to another bucket.
   What i would like to do is copy that PDF and create a jpg of each page. i currently have a back end process doing this with imagemagick but would like to move it into my lambda function maybe with using gm?

Here is my current code.

```
var params = {
    CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + srcKey,
    Bucket: destinationbucket,
    Key: outfile.pdf
};

s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    context.succeed('exit');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagic is available for NodeJS Lambda functions. From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html):

> If you author your Lambda function code in Node.js, the following
>   libraries are available in the AWS Lambda execution environment so you
>   don't need to include them:
>
> ImageMagick: Installed with default settings. For versioning
>   information, see imagemagick nodejs wrapper  and  ImageMagick native
>   binary  (search for "ImageMagick").

So you should be able to move your current solution to Lambda fairly easily.